# Running Sonar behind Microsoft IIS with SSL enabled fails to redirect to https after successfull login

Tags: iis, https, sonarqube

I have configured Sonar webserver to have all of the requests to go through Microsoft IIS server. 
It was confirmed to work fine with requests via http protocol.

1. However, once the https was enabled, after successful login, Sonar webapp is trying to redirect to non-https url, causing it to timeout. If I then go and change the url to go to https, it shows as authenticated and continues to work as normal.
2. The same issue happens when you trying to logout - instead of redirecting to https page, it goes out to http.

What needs to be done to make Sonar post-login action to use the same protocol via which the login page was requested originally?

sonar.properties has:

```
sonar.web.host:                           127.0.0.1
sonar.web.port:                           9000
sonar.web.context:                        /sonar
```

IIS plugin has:

```
<VirtualHostGroup Name="default_host">        
    <VirtualHost Name="*:80"/>
    <VirtualHost Name="*:9443"/>
    <VirtualHost Name="*:443"/>
    <VirtualHost Name="*:9000"/>
</VirtualHostGroup>

<ServerGroup Name="sonar_group">
    <Server Name="sonar_server">      
        <Transport Hostname="127.0.0.1" Port="9000" Protocol="http"/>
    </Server>
</ServerGroup>

<UriGroup Name="sonar_host_URIs">
    <Uri Name="/sonar*"/>
</UriGroup>

<Route ServerGroup="sonar_group" UriGroup="sonar_host_URIs" VirtualHostGroup="default_host"/>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the web UI (while logged in as an admin user), go to Settings -> General and make sure the URL listed under Server Base URL starts with "https".  This can also be set in the server's sonar.properties file using sonar.core.serverBaseURL

Comment: Hi John, thanks for the suggestion, however it didn't solve the problem.

What I also noticed that, while performing certain actions, sonar webapp is trying to redirect to non-https version of url, for example:

Comment: when clicking on 'Issues' link at the top menu, or after deleting a project. 
To me it seems like the redirection and navigation logic is not consistent throughout the webapp links, in some cases it correctly uses originated https path, in some cases it falls back to just http.

Answer (score 0):

This is a [well-known issue](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-270) with the Ruby stack, and requires tweaking the web-server config -- not that of Sonar. On Apache you'd have to do the following, Im sure the pointers in the ticket will also lead you to a solution for IIS:

```
RequestHeader set X_FORWARDED_PROTO "https"
```